# apply std::transform to every nth element

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++20

Is there a way to construct an iterator from another one which will always advance (in the sense of `std::advance`) by a number `n`? I would like to pass an iterator to `std::transform` but the transformation should only happening on every `n`th element. Do I need to write these things on my own? (`std::execution::par_unseq` should still be possible).

Comment: You mean, [`views::stride`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/stride_view)?

Comment: @康桓瑋 `views::stride` is C++23 and is also not compatible with `std::execution::par_unseq`.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Why would it not be compatible?  The linked documentation says that it models random access range if the underlying sequence does, which should be sufficient for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an index array and use that for your source for transform
to iterate over. This can then be done in parallel

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<double> vals = { ... }; // source values to transform

std::vector<size_t> indices; // 0, n, 2n, 3n, ...
for (size_t i = 0; i < vals.size(); i += n)
   indices.push_back(i);

std::vector<double> out; // holds every nth result
std::transform(indices.begin(), indices.end(),
               std::back_inserter(out),
               [&](size_t i) -> double {
                   return 3.1415 * vals[i]; // function on nth val 
               });
```

Comment: or maybe just a custom iterator with an atomic increment in it instead of building up all that memory that will have to be loaded along with the actual data?   (haven't done C++ in a while though)and skip having to do a single-threaded run through the length of the data set.

Comment: @xaxxon I am assuming creating the `indices` list is cheap relative to the function in the `std::transform`.